# Issue with run Google Play Intergity code on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, dependencies, google-play-integrity-api

I'm trying to run a next code on Google Cloud Functions platform:

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    invoker
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.4'
    invoker 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker:java-function-invoker:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-playintegrity:v1-rev20230105-2.0.0'
}

tasks.register("runFunctionGetMetadata", JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker'
    classpath(configurations.invoker)
    inputs.files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output)
    args('--target', 'com.k.backend.GetMetadata', '--port', 8081)
    doFirst {
        args('--classpath', files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output).asPath)
    }
}
```

Java:

```
package com.k.backend;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1.PlayIntegrity;
import com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1.PlayIntegrityRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1.model.DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1.model.DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class GetMetadata implements HttpFunction {

    @Override
    public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.addProperty("calc1", calc(arg + 1)); // arg is just random string
        object.addProperty("calc2", calc(arg));
        String result = new Gson().toJson(object);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        BufferedWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(result);
    }

    private String calc(String integrityToken) {
        try {
            DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest requestObj = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest();
            requestObj.setIntegrityToken(integrityToken);

            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("../client_secret.json"));
            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

            HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
            GoogleClientRequestInitializer initialiser = new PlayIntegrityRequestInitializer();

            PlayIntegrity.Builder playIntegrity = new PlayIntegrity.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer).setApplicationName("AppName")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(initialiser);
            PlayIntegrity play = playIntegrity.build();

            DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse response = play.v1().decodeIntegrityToken("com.k", requestObj).execute();
            return someActionOnResponse(response);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Once I'm trying to deploy my code to Goole Cloud Functions backend I get error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: ...k.backend.GetMetadata
[INFO] 11 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.054 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-16T05:03:52Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project backend: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/k/backend/GetMetadata.java:[9,48] package com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1 does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/k/backend/GetMetadata.java:[10,48] package com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1 does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/k/backend/GetMetadata.java:[11,54] package com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1.model does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/k/backend/GetMetadata.java:[12,54] package com.google.api.services.playintegrity.v1.model does not exist
[ERROR] /workspace/src/main/java/com/k/backend/GetMetadata.java:[78,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest
[ERROR]   location: class com.k.backend.GetMetadata
....
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance :)

Update: sorry, my bad, I forgot add dependencies to POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-playintegrity</artifactId>
  <version>v1-rev20230105-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it working fine, thanks!

Comment: Can you try deploying your code locally and check whether it is deploying successfully or not? Also to complete all the missing parts of the build.gradle you must include `com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.32.1` under dependencies part.